# Add Icons to the Product Category Sidebar Widget WooCommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, widgets, sidebar

I have been searching for this since yesterday. It's weird the little info is there about this simple function, I suppose that's because the answer is too obvious. But I didn't find the way to display icons in the product category sidebar widget.

I found this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/ to add images/icons to the categories, but that's how far I am. I don't know how to add them to the product category widget. Or if it is any easier way to do this. Is there any plugin?

Any advise and answer is appreciated. Thank you.